# Using a non-ActiveRecord model, can't access it through rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, activerecord

(**Rails 4.2.4**) Hello, beginner here. I am working on a project which does not need a DB or activeRecord. Therefore, when making my Rails project I appended the -O (to disable Active Record and database) (rails new MyApp -O)

I read that to do a model not backed by a database you can just create a file in

app/models/site.rb.

No need to do:

rails generate model Site

So I added my model, which looks something like this:

```
class Site

attr_reader   :name
attr_reader   :out_average
attr_reader   :in_average
attr_reader   :change

def initialize(name, in_average, out_average)
    @name        = name
    @out_average = out_average
    @in_average  = in_average
    @change      = find_increase
end

def find_increase()
    if @in_average && @out_average != 0
        @change = ((@in_average - @out_average)/@out_average)*100
    else
        @change = 0
    end

    return @change

end
end
```

So, I then started up console "rails c" and when I try to invoke a new Site object, I get an error:

**irb(main):001:0> Site.new**

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Site
from (irb):1
from /home/ms-87/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /home/ms-87/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/ms-87/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /home/ms-87/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/ms-87/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ms-87/Documents/projects/rails_projects/site_seasonality/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ms-87/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/ms-87/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I made sure I started the console from the root of my app. I also made sure to use the proper naming convention (site.rb is the filename in app/model/, "Site" is the name of my class inside the file). Can anyone help me as to why this isn't working? Is my thinking here wrong? Thanks.

Comment: That should definitely work! I did the same thing and it runs fine. My guess is you have a typo somewhere. What happens when you run this in the Rails console? `require_relative "./app/models/site.rb"`

Comment: I checked your code and it runs nicely for me, with `Site.new("foo", 2,3)` returning new object. Did you make any other changes in other files (a syntax error in other file might be causing that)? what happens if you run `load 'app/models/site.rb'` from console?

Comment: Ahh, damn, I just realized my error. My first error was that my filenames were capitalized "Site.rb", I had actually fixed this before I posted. But after I fixed it, I accidentally started using "irb" instead of "rails c". DOH!

Thanks guys, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My first error was that my filenames were capitalized "Site.rb", I had actually fixed this before I posted. But after I fixed it, I accidentally started using "irb" instead of "rails c". DOH! Sorry for the post.